# Pop up requiring a specific answer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup something to have a little fun with my co-workers where when they click a button in Excel it will force them to answer a bunch of math problems before unlocking their system. If they get it wrong I want it to play a funny sound.

That said I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this and I'm not finding a lot online that does what I'm looking for.

What I have so far isn't working. I keep getting the following error:
"Expected sub function or property"

What I have so far is pretty basic, any help would be greatly appreciated though.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim URL As String

'Lockout Functions
   'Cancel = True

'Check for Muted Sound, Unmute

'First Question
    a = Application.InputBox("What is 1+1?")
    If a = "2" Then 'continue
    Else goto a
    Application.Speech.Speak "Are you even trying?"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If

'Second Question
    b = Application.InputBox("Finish this Sequence 1123_813__")
    If b = "1123581321" Then 'Continue
    Else goto b
    Application.Speech.Speak "It's the Fibonacci duh!"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If  

'Third Question
    c = Application.InputBox("What are the next three numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ?")
    If c = "1,4,9,16,25,36,49" Then 'continue
    Else goto c
    Application.Speech.Speak "Terrible!"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If

'Unlock/Return Control
    'Cancel = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you intend with `Else a`, `Else b` and `Else c`?

Comment: Should be a Goto in order loop back to the question if they get it wrong. IE they can't continue till they get the question right.

Comment: You need a line/label with [`GoTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement) - but I'd recommend against it, it leads to spaghetti code. You could use a `Do... Loop While` loop instead.

Comment: So something like ` Loop While Not Text = "2" ` ?? I'm not sure of the syntax in this case

Comment: @Deke Shouldn't your answer for `c` be `25, 36, 49`?

Comment: @BigBen Figured it out, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @dwirony that's what the answer is, yes, I'm just making them type it all out.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a, b and c into the `ELSE`

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim URL As String

'Lockout Functions
   'Cancel = True

'Check for Muted Sound, Unmute

'First Question
    a = Application.InputBox("What is 1+1?")
    If a = "2" Then 'continue
    Else
    Application.Speech.Speak "Are you even trying?"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If

'Second Question
    b = Application.InputBox("Finish this Sequence 1123_813__")
    If b = "1123581321" Then 'Continue
    Else
    Application.Speech.Speak "It's the Fibonacci duh!"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If  

'Third Question
    c = Application.InputBox("What are the next three numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ?")
    If c = "1,4,9,16,25,36,49" Then 'continue
    Else
    Application.Speech.Speak "Terrible!"
    MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
    End If

'Unlock/Return Control
    'Cancel = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This is really close. Only thing is I want it to loop the question if they don't get it right.

Comment: @Deke I have edited my answer. Please let me know if is more helpful now.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for pointing those out. I've been working with vb.net before, but it was not VBA and it's been a while.